# Самоприсваивание переменной при определении

Tags: c++, c

Встретил в коде участок следующего вида:

```
int a = a;
```

компиляция проходит успешно. Вопрос - **Как это работает?**

Comment: а можно кусок кода по больше, может это локальная переменная?

Comment: В чем вы тут видите проблему? О чем именно вопрос?

Comment: Извините, но код показать не могу. Собственно исчерпывающий ответ уже получен!

Comment: @Idrt я рад, что вам помогли в этот раз, но что ответить на такой вопрос  это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N1256 6.2.1/7

> Any other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator .

То есть область видимости имени переменной начинается сразу после `declarator`. В Вашем случае в инициализаторе имя уже видно и может быть использовано. Это значит, что Вы можете инициализировать переменную саму собой, соответственно при этом она получит неопределенное значение.

К слову, в C++ действует такое же правило, и это значит, что возможно скопировать еще неинициализированный объект:

```
Some s1 = s1;
std::string s1 = s2;
```

Если (и, как правило), конструктор копирования никак не обрабатывает "самокопирование", то объект после такой "инициализации" будет пребывать в неопределенном состоянии.

Comment: Премного Вам благодарен.

Comment: А точнее попытка обращения к неинициализированной переменной является неопределенным поведением, и что там будет дальше, и будет ли вообще 0 неизвестно.

Comment: @VTT не понял причем здесь ноль. Ну и прямо из стандарта c++: ```unsigned char x = 12; { unsigned char x = x; } Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.```

Comment: Хм, ноль действительно не при чем. Наверное новая клавиатура провоцирует на опечатки.

Comment: @Croessmah, В C++, если переменная `a` имеет автоматический класс памяти, то конструкция вида `some_type a = a;` корректна только в том случае, если `some_type` — это беззнаковый узкий символьный тип или `std::byte`, в противном случае поведение программы не определено. [dcl.init, 11.6/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#12).

Answer (score -2):

После того, как переменная была объявлена, ей сразу же было присвоено какое то значение (даже если ее не инициализировать), равное тому мусору, которое было в выделенной памяти до нее. Действительно, хотелось бы увидеть код, где это используется, но например так можно получить какое то случайное целое число.

Comment: Которое там оставил предыдущий процесс....