# Указатель на самого себя

Tags: c++, указатели, void

Не могу понять, как и почему работает эта программа.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  void* x = &x;
  std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @AlexF почему можно брать адрес самого себя ещё до того как закончилось определение?

Comment: потому что место под `x` при инициализации уже выделено

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Самоприсваивание переменной при определении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797680/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Comment: @wololo но тут неопределенного значения нет? Можно пользоваться спокойно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Присвоить адрес локальной переменной самой себе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555629/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%b5).

Comment: @wololo спасибо, поставьте тревогу с дубликатом на вопрос, тогда я вроде смогу принять его

Answer (score -2):

Здесь у вас неопределенное поведение, которое заключается в том, что вам кажется что программа работает корректно. Неопределенное поведение возникает потому что вы пытаетесь получить адрес неинициализированной переменной.

Comment: Можно конкретней где и почему неопределённое поведение?

Comment: @riot дополнил ответ

Comment: Получение адреса неинициализированный переменной не является неопределенным поведением.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/497813)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Почему не является ответом на вопрос?

Comment: @AlexF Да мое дело — очередь проверок. Вижу ответ без кода, маленький и с минусом, голосую за удаление. Если он хорош — я не виноват т.к. в очереди голосует за "_Выглядит_ нормально" и "_Рекомендовать_ удаление", проверяющий не обязан  знать все метки/языки.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica "проверяющий не обязан знать все метки/языки", - на это очень хочется нагрубить в ответ. Но я отвечу, что у проверяющего есть кнопка "Пропустить", нажимайте ее если не понимаете о чем речь в тексте.

Comment: @AlexF Ну окей, не спорю.